# part of body tag remains in file_get_contents output, how to remove it

Tags: php

I am getting the content of a web-page using file_get_contents and part of the body tag remains in the output. I am also using strip_tags() to remove other html tags, but the partial body tag remains.

How can I remove it?

The output I am getting is body> and then content.

Here is my code:

```
$content = file_get_contents( $url );
$content = stristr( $content, "body" );
echo strip_tags($content);
```

Comment: What are you exactly about to do? Embedding the website into your page? Or do you want to extract special information from that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stristr` returns starting from the index where the matched string *starts*, but you actually one one character after it *ends*:

```
$content = substr(strpos($content, "<body>") + strlen("<body>") + 1);
```

You also want to search for "" rather than "body", as "body" might appear in the actual content. Since you're using `strip_tags` anyway, however, you can actually grab starting at the beginning of the body tag and it will work just fine:

```
$content = stristr($content, "<body>");
```

This will return the content starting with `<body>`, which will be stripped off by `strip_tags`.